# How can I separate my texts based on spam or not spam?

Tags: python, excel, csv, jupyter

I am still new to Python/Jupyter.
I have an excel file which I have imported into Python with 2 columns- one is a binary 1/0 (1 for spam and 0 for non-spam) and the second is a text message. I am trying to create 2 wordclouds, one for spam and one for non-spam. How could I separate my texts into spam and non-spam?
[Screenshot of my spreadsheet for clarity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwtsz.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sort by the binary value, either ascending so (0 first) or descending (1 first).

Once done save the excel file then import as you usually do.

Answer (score 0):

assume your csv file is called test.csv with two cols called 'text' and 'label'

```py
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")

df_spam = df[df.label == 1]
df_no_spam = df[df.label == 0]
```

Comment: Thsnk you, thats helped